# Boot Strap wont span correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html

I've been building a website with bootstrap as the framework and for some reason in one section it wont span all the way across the screen.

Heres how it should look:
[image]

and

[image]

Heres the code i've been using:

```
<section class="section_area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">

                   <!-- Title-->
                   <div class="span4 title">
                        <span class="arrow_left"></span>
                        <h3>What we do</h3>
                        <h1>simplify your business processes</h1>
                        <p>Sollemnes wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip consequat.</p>
                    </div>
                     <!-- End Title-->

                    <!-- Services-->
                    <div class="span8 services">
                        <!-- Row-->
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <!-- Item Service-->
                            <div class="span6">
                                <h4 class="text_right">Responsive Desing</h4>
                                <div class="item_service">
                                    <div class="image_service">
                                        <img src="img/1.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info_service">
                                        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Item Service-->  

                           <!-- Item Service-->
                            <div class="span6">
                                <h4>Retina Desing</h4>
                                <div class="item_service_right">
                                    <div class="image_service">
                                        <img src="img/2.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info_service">
                                        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Item Service-->                   
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Row-->

                         <!-- Row-->
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <!-- Item Service-->
                            <div class="span6">
                                <h4 class="text_right">Full Validated</h4>
                                <div class="item_service">
                                    <div class="image_service">
                                        <img src="img/3.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info_service">
                                        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Item Service-->  

                           <!-- Item Service-->
                            <div class="span6">
                                <h4>Social Media</h4>
                                <div class="item_service_right">
                                    <div class="image_service">
                                        <img src="img/4.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info_service">
                                        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Item Service-->                   
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Row-->
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Services-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- End section area-->



        <!-- section area-->
        <section class="section_area content_resalt">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <!-- Tabs-->
                    <div class="span12">
                        <!-- Nav Tabs-->

                        <!-- End Nav Tabs-->

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        <div class="switcher-panel"></div>    

                        <!-- 1-content -->
                        <div id="1-content" class="switcher-content set2 show">

                            <!-- Features -->
                            <div class="span8">

                                <h2>Windows Solutions</h2>
                                <div class="row-fluid feature">
                                    <div class="span4">
                                        <h3>Features</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span4">
                                        <h3> Account free </h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span4">
                                        <h3>Account Premium</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  

                                <div class="row-fluid feature">
                                    <div class="span5">
                                        <p>Complete Social Marketing Suite</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3 premium">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 

                                <div class="row-fluid feature">
                                    <div class="span5">
                                        <p>Social Network</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3 premium">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 

                                <div class="row-fluid feature">
                                    <div class="span5">
                                        <p>Full Responsive Web  Desing</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3 premium">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 

                                <div class="row-fluid feature">
                                    <div class="span5">
                                        <p>Retina Desing</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <img src="img/icons/error.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3 premium">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 

                                <div class="row-fluid feature">
                                    <div class="span5">
                                        <p>Python And Django</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <img src="img/icons/error.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3 premium">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 

                                <div class="row-fluid feature">
                                    <div class="span5">
                                        <p>Full Documentation And Support</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3">
                                        <img src="img/icons/error.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span3 premium">
                                        <img src="img/icons/ok.png" alt="Image">
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Features -->

                            <!-- Title -->
                            <div class="span4 title_right">                                
                                <span class="arrow_right"></span>
                                <h3>Get started</h3>
                                <h1>today witha a free trial!</h1>
                                <h5>30 days free trial | No credit card required | $13/mo after end of trial period.</h5>
                                <div class="clearfix padding_top_mini"></div>
                                <a href="#" class="button big">Try Free</a>
                                <a href="#" class="button big">Buy Now</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Title -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- End 1-content -->


                    </div>
                    <!-- End Tabs-->                    

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- End section area-->
```

Also the live version is [here](http://divisionforty.com)

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.container` is using the properties from `bootstrap-responsive.css`, which is setting `max-width: 680px`. That's just causing everything to squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `<div class="container">` that is inside the `.section_area`

Comment: I appreciate the help! Unfortunately i can not up vote your answer

Comment: how so? It's the exact same answer as above?

Comment: i didn't have enough reputation, 15 is required.